# Need assistance with code so that it comes back and displays the "Menu"

Tags: c++, c++11, default-constructor

I am making a small project, using variables and classes:

http://pastebin.com/NpU6E4e5

When I change variables using the default constructor their values don't change.

```
water::water()
{       
    cout<<"What would you like to do?"<<endl;

    cout<<"0. Get current stats of water"<<endl;
    cout<<"1. Raise water temperature by certain degrees"<<endl;
    cout<<"2. Decrease water temperature by certain degrees"<<endl;

    cin >> do_what;
    cout<<do_what;

    switch(do_what)
    {
        case 0 :check_status();
                break;
        case 1 :heat_water();
                break;
        default:cout<<"Enter proper value!"<<endl;
                //system("cls");
                //water();
                break;      
    }
}
```

This is the default constructor. It is not able to change variable values which are declared in its main class which is `class water`

Comment: display part of your code here and explain problem more

Comment: Each of those functions you're calling in the case statements create an unnamed temporary `water` instance. Is that why you think your changes are not altering variables? If not, work on reducing the code. I'm sure you can trim away 90% of what you've linked to and be able to reproduce the problem. Chances are, while doing that you'll realize what the problem is.

Comment: Besides the fact that links to code are not encouraged here, that is too much code to go through to figure out what the problem is. Please try to create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and post it.

Comment: Do you mean to say I cannot modify them in a default Constructor? Should I move the functions calls to main instead?

Comment: What is *them*? Of course you can initialize/assign/modify class members within the constructor. As I said, you need to reduce the code into a small example that demonstrates what is going wrong.

Comment: Ok I have shortened the code so it is easier to read. What do you mean by unnamed temperary "water" instance? I dont quite understand what that it.

Comment: In add_temp() for example, the last statement is "water();". What that is really doing is creating another instance of water then calling the default constructor on that instance. That is a temporary value, and is destroyed at the end of the statement (before add_temp() returns). It would be more clear to state "water temporary();"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `main` function you create a `water` object named `w1` which is what you are working with. When you are calling functions (e.g. `add_ph`, `add_temp`) on THAT object and you call `water()` again, that does not reconstruct the `w1` object: you are creating a *new* `water` object, constructing it and then it gets destructed straight away. You can see this by putting a break point in `water::water` and `water::~water` (the constructor and destructor, respectively).

If you are trying to modify the original `water` object, `w1`, you should create a `Reset` function which resets things back to what you want (which I assume is to print the console stuff and ask for user input again?).

You may also want to try something like the following:

```
int main()
{
    // create water object to work with
    water w1;

    char input = 'Q';
    do
    {
        // Ask user for input
        input = AskForInput();
        ProcessInput(input, w1);
        // Process input until the user wishes to quit
    } while (input != 'Q')

    return 0;
}
```

Note this answer is based on the code linked and your original question.